# File Path System On Web

Tags: c#, html, path

File paths look like `"wwwroot\\documents\\file.png"` but web platforms don't like this style, the `img` HTML tag `src` value wants `"/wwwroot/documents/file.png"`.

`System.IO.Path.Combine` does not meet my needs.

What can I do except `Replace("\\","/");`?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: URI ≠ file path. Use proper classes, not strings, to represent these objects, and this problem won’t occur. *Don’t* use string replacement methods here instead of proper types. They’re a hack.